# Mixing embedded VB in HTML asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Please explain why my counter variable "i" in the IIF statement is causing a compilation error and suggest a solution:

```
<span>
    <select>
        <%For i = 1 to 10 %> 
            <option value="<%=i%>" <%#IIF(Eval("Employee.Id") = i,"selected='selected'","") %> ><%=i%></option>
        <%Next i %>
    </select>
</span>
```

Error Message:

"i" is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Cannot resolve symbol "i"

Comment: @David see above. Thanks!

Comment: Why have a pound sign? Doesn't look like you are binding any variable. Have you tried an equal sign? The best way would be to have a list of numbers and bind that list to the dropdown and set the Employee.Id as the selected value.

Comment: @the_lotus what pound sign are you referring to? I see no pound sign in my code. I can't use the equals sign because I am using Eval() to bind to the Employee item which is my datasource. Thus I need a hash sign instead.

Comment: @Mattkoen here we call it "pound sign" ;) I think your option would be to do it in the code behind.